# Confleunt demo (cp-demo) coughs on jq. How to add to docker?

Tags: docker, confluent-platform

I am trying to run the Confluent demo (which I cloned from https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo).

I get through all the steps up to starting the services in docker. This command:

`/usr/mferris/cp-demo/scripts/start.sh`

spits back:

`ERROR: This script requires 'jq'. Please install 'jq' and run again.`

I can install jq using brew—but that doesn't put it into my docker image.  If I try to pull it into docker with: 
`docker pull jq`

I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Anyone know how I can add jq to get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install below dependencies on your host machine and then run start.sh, you don't need jq in docker image, this is used by stasrt.sh script for json parsing

1. Docker version 17.06.1-ce
2. Docker Compose version 1.14.0 with Docker Compose file format 2.2
3. Java version 1.8.0_92
4. MacOS 10.14.3 (note for Ubuntu environments(https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo/issues/53))
5. git
6. jq

Comment: Thanks, updating java from 1.8.0_91 and then re-installing jq seems to have done it. It's exceedingly slow coming up, but I think that's because bringing up confluent in Docker sucks up so much memory.